# Need to Update Offdate of Component Only Where it's Used Alongside Another Component

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to update the offdate of a component (322058-000000') of a parent part where the component in questions is used along with another component.

The following code gives me the component (322058-000000) and the instance where it needs to be changed. It needs to be changed where it is used along with component (322123-301200).

```
select * from BomStructure BS
where 
Component = '322058-000000' and
exists (select 1 from BomStructure 
        where ParentPart = BS.ParentPart and Component = '322123-301200');
```

I only want to update the offdate for component 322058-000000 as per the results of the query above. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here, assuming the result of your existing query is the row or rows you want to update, you just need to convert your `SELECT` statement into an `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE BS
SET OffDate = <The value you need here>
from BomStructure BS
where 
Component = '322058-000000' and
exists (select 1 from BomStructure 
        where ParentPart = BS.ParentPart and Component = '322123-301200');
```

Comment: Thanks for that :) but I should've worked that one out myself.

Comment: No worries, and you're welcome. Sometimes we all get in too deep sorting out the hard parts of a query and need a little nudge to come up for air and see that there's an easy part, too!